# Javascript - can't resolve this 'warning: promise was created in a handler'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, bluebird

Using sequelize.js in a nodejs app, and I have a `promise.all` that takes two promises (a `user` query, and a `color` query):

```
router.get(`/someEndPoint`, (req, res) => {
    let userAccount = user.findOne({
        where: {
            id: //some ID
        }
    });

    let colorStuff = color.findOne({
        where: {
            colorName: //some color
        }
    })

    Promise.all([userAccount , colorStuff ]).then(([result1, result2]) => {
        //do stuff, such as:
        res.send('success');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```

At the part that says `//do stuff`, my console keeps giving me this warning:

```
a promise was created in a handler at... but was not returned from it, 
see (URL that I can't post) at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this. I thought after the `.then` that the promises are resolved?

Comment: what code do you have at `do stuff` - or does even having just that comment cause the same warning? also, I don't think `let user = user.findOne ... etc` is your real code, is it? wouldn't there be an error about duplicate declaration of user? seeing as user must exists for user.findOne to work, how can you let user = the result of that?

Comment: `a handler` - what is this `handler` the error speaks of?

Comment: So the `//do stuff` is normally a `res.send('success')`, or a `res.send([result1, result2])`..... as for `handler`, I have no idea what that means..... and yes, `let user` is not my real code..... I have changed it in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without other context, but perhaps you need to return the Promise.all

```
return Promise.all([user, color])...
```

From the bluebird docs here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/warning-explanations.md#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it

if there are any other promises created in the // do stuff area, be sure to return those as well.

Comment: Added an extra comment from reading the bluebird docs. Good luck tracking it down! It really sounds like there is some promise somewhere that needs returning.

Comment: Hey, you were right. The inner part of my code needed a `return` statement, as per linked documents. Thanks!